# JAXB xml validation

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb, xsd

Within xsd schema I use inheritance from class that is not defined in schema (for erhitectural reason is it in other module/package) defined as:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="RemoteHost">
   <xsd:annotation>
     <xsd:appinfo>  
       <jaxb:class ref="com.dummy.entities.RemoteHost"></jaxb:class>
     </xsd:appinfo>
   </xsd:annotation>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

For example, child classes are defined within same xsd document as:

```
<xsd:complexType name="hostFirstSubType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="RemoteHost">
        </xsd:extension>        
    </xsd:complexContent>        
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="otherHostType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="RemoteHost">
            <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int" />
        </xsd:extension>            
    </xsd:complexContent>        
</xsd:complexType>
```

Class that is sublclassed within xsd is defined as:

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "GenericRemoteHost",propOrder = {
        "address",
        "username",
        "password",
        "sshPort"
    })
public class RemoteHost {

    @XmlElement(required = true, namespace = "http://com/dummy/entities/RemoteHost")
    protected String  address;
    @XmlElement
    protected String  username;
    @XmlElement
    protected String  password;
    @XmlElement
    protected Integer sshPort;
    ...
```

Sample part of xml to load:

```
        <hostFirstSubType>
            <rh:address>127.0.0.1</rh:address>
            <rh:username>user</rh:username>
            <rh:password>pass</rh:password>                             
            <rh:sshPort>22</rh:sshPort>             
        </hostFirstSubType>

        <otherHostType id="1">
            <rh:address>127.0.0.1</rh:address>
            <rh:username>user</rh:username>
            <rh:password>pass</rh:password>                             
            <rh:sshPort>22</rh:sshPort>             
        </otherHostType>
```

I created a validation collector to display all validation errors during unmarshalling of xml file against that  schema and result is somehow confusing:
Validation collector shows validation error for each class inheriting my RemoteHost as:

> Element 'hostFirstSubType' must have no character or element
>   information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
>
> Element 'otherHostType' must have no character or element information
>   item [children], because the type's content type is empty

However, when I skip validation part, xml file is properly loaded into java objects, all data is loaded and accessibile with both getters and setters.

As sugested at some other posts, I tried to change @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) to other available values but without luck.

Anybody have a clue what else to look for...

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing matches what you have:

1. Your XML contains elements that are not defined in your XML schema therefore you are getting validation errors.
2. Your XML contains elements that are mapped to your object model, and this is working correctly.

Things you can do:

1. Include the definition for the XML elements in your document to the XML schema.
2. Make the definition for your XML elements more flexible leveraging the `any` concept.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what to do. Regarding xml, it does not contain any data that is not defined within superclass. I tried to add some xsd definition of superclass directly to xsd like defining sequence element within RemoteHost definition in xsd but problem persist. Can you, please, help me with some example or link...